# Учет НДФЛ в ERP 2.0

Tags: 1с, erp

**1С Конфигурация ERP 2.0.**
При расчете НДФЛ в начислении зарплаты, попадают суммы по излишне удержанному НДФЛ, которых быть не должно. Куда посмотреть чтобы понять откуда это идет? Потратил кучу времени на отладку и так и не пришел ни к чему.

Comment: Думаю, стоит посмотреть в код.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, разобрался в вопросе.
Суммы по НДФЛ попадающие в документы начисления содержаться в регистрах накопления ***"СведенияОДоходахНДФЛ"***, ***"РасчетыНалогоплательщиковСБюджетомПоНДФЛ"***, ***"РасчетыНалоговыхАгентовСБюджетомПоНДФЛ"***.
В результате непоследовательного ввода документов возникли различия в начисленных и удержанных суммах, что можно легко увидеть если получить данные из регистра *"РасчетыНалогоплательщиковСБюджетомПоНДФЛ"* с видом удержания "Удержано" и  данные регистра *"СведенияОДоходахНДФЛ"*, получив от последних 13%.
 Отняв суммы из регистра *"РасчетыНалогоплательщиковСБюджетомПоНДФЛ"* от сумм из *"СведенияОДоходахНДФЛ"* получим излишне удержанный НДФЛ.
 
В моём случае неправильно рассчитывалась сумма излишне удержанного НДФЛ (ее не должно было быть вообще), и решить ее удалось удалив из регистра *"РасчетыНалогоплательщиковСБюджетомПоНДФЛ"* все движения с видом "Расход" и создав на каждую запись прихода, точно такую же (для регистратора использовался документ "Перенос данных") с видом движения "Расход" и видом удержания "Удержано". После чего суммы по излишне удержанному НДФЛ перестали появляться при автоматическом расчете документа.